# cast custom type to "option" custom type

Tags: ocaml

I'm new with Ocaml and functional programming, and I'm trying to implement some data structures that respect some component interfaces. At the moment I'm the problem with the following error

```
File "src/symbol_table.ml", line 24, characters 39-45:
24 |   { variables=Hashtbl.create 0; parent=Option(table) }
                                            ^^^^^^
Error: This variant expression is expected to have type dec option
       The constructor Option does not belong to type option
Command exited with code 2.
```

And I'm trying to implement the following interface

```
type dec

val begin_block : dec -> dec
```

With the following implementation

```
type dec = {
  variables: (Ast.identifier, Ast.typ) Hashtbl.t;
  parent: dec option
}

let begin_block (table: dec) =
  logger#debug "Starting scope";
  { variables=Hashtbl.create 0; parent=table }
```

I think that my Java knowledge is the limit here, and my question is how I can make the cast to type dec option? to set the table as a parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `option` in OCaml is a [variant](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/variants.html) that can hold one of two things :

- either a value that signifies there is content and what the value is, noted `Some(value)`
- either a value that signifies there is no content, noted `None`

So a `dec option` is a type that is an option that can hold `dec` values. Either it has a value using `Some` or it doesn't have a value, using `None`.

To answer your question, you need to replace `parent=table` with `parent=Some(table)`.

If you wanted to signify that there was no parent you would have `parent=None`.

I highly recommend you go and read up on variants and `Option` in OCaml, as they are extremely useful power features of the language.

There's some more explanations of what `Option` is in this [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498796/ocaml-what-data-type-is-some-and-none/21498998)

Comment: how to happen with a new language, my question was very stupid. Thank you for introducing a good starting point for me about the option value :-D

Comment: No problem! And there's no stupid questions, we all have to start somewhere!
I found this tutorial that could help out : https://sanette.github.io/ocaml-tutorial/4.06/coreexamples.html